# change resource file (resx file) with c#

Tags: c#, reflection

in c# by reflection change resource file look like below:

```
using (ResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResourceWriter(PathName))
        {
            foreach (var textItem in selectedText)
            {
                resourceWriter.AddResource(textItem.Id, textItem.Name);
            }
        }
```

a selectedText is List of Id and Name instead of name and value.
when run test a destroy resource file and not opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [ResXResourceWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resxresourcewriter?view=netframework-4.8) class

```
using (ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(PathName))
{
    foreach (var textItem in selectedText)
    {
        resourceWriter.AddResource(textItem.Id, textItem.Name);
    }

    resourceWriter.Close();
}
```